# Image Replacement Script (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I'm building an employee bios page where the client wants selected thumbnails to display in color at full opacity and all others at lower opacity in black and white. Which wouldn't be hard - the trouble is, every thumbnail has to have a color state and a black and white state. So my next thought was to swap out the black and white image (which would be resting within the div with a color background image) on mouseover.

```
$('.thumbnail').mouseenter(function(){
    var current = $(this); // cache thing
    var thishtml = current.html(); // get contents of thing
    current.html('').mouseleave(function(){ //empty the thing
        current.html(thishtml); //put the variable back in the thing
        });
});
```

My HTML would be as follows:

```
<div class = "thumbnail" style = "background-image: url(color.jpg);">
<img src="blackandwhite.jpg" />
</div>
```

Obviously, since I'm asking the question, my idea didn't work. The mouseover removes the innerHTML, and the variable is converted successfully, but it doesn't get inserted into the DIV again. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of swapping HTML use css.

CSS:

```
.hidden {
     visibility:hidden
}
```

JS:

```
$(".thumbnail").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).find('img').addClass('hidden')
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('img').removeClass('hidden')
  }
);
```

Comment: Great. Click the check mark on the left to select this as the accepted answer. We both get rep points.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .show() and hide() to make the blackandwhite.jpg image visible and hidden respectively.

```
$(".thumbnail").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).children("img").hide(); //hide b and w on mouse in
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).children("img").show();  //showb and w on mouse out
  }
);
```

Comment: if "thumbnail" doesn't have a defined width and height, hiding the IMG will make the entire DIV disappear since it has no contents.

Answer (score 0):

When you empty the `html` there is nothing on which your `mouseleave` event will fire to set the `html` back again.

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yQpze/). In this demo I am just setting a character show that you can see the event getting fired, remove the character, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Javascript to do that, just a piece of CSS:

```
 div.thumbnail {
   background-image: url(blackandwhite.jpg);
   opacity: 0.7;
 }
 div.thumbnail:hover {
   background-image: url(color.jpg);
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying using the show and hide methods?  Be sure to specify a width for the containing divs, or the entire thing will disappear when hiding or showing.  I'm guessing the thumbnails are all the same size, so it will be easy to add CSS such as:

CSS:

```
.thumbnail
{
   width: 100px;
   height; 100px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('img', '.thumbnail').hide();//Start off hidden
   $('.thumbnail').mouseenter(function()
   {
      $('img', this).show();
   });
   $('.thumbnail').mouseleave(function()
   {
      $('img', this).hide();
   });
});
```